# SQLServer - SQLServerException with jdbc access

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have installed on my pc ms sqlserver express 2012, I am trying to reach it via jdbc but I am not successfull, I get the error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: 
"Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. 
Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host 
and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP 
connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall

I am accessing via the following url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mytest;"
I enabled the tcp/ip via the Sql server configuration manager, but if I run netstat-an I can't see the 1433 port listening.
I disabled windows firewall too... 
I am lost :(
Any help?
Thank you!

*******UPDATE*********
I could overcome the problem by enabling port 1433 on IpAll under Sql Server configuration manager - Sql Server Network configuration - Protocols for SQLEXPRESS - tcp-ip Properties - Ip Addresses. But now I get another error:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: error is not in english so it will be difficult for us to point out the cause.Can you translate the error to english?

Comment: Enabling TCP/IP is not sufficient, also verify if it is configured to run on port 1433 (by default it runs on a random port)

Comment: Sorry for that, I fixed it with the translation

Comment: I could overcome the problem by enabling port 1433 on IpAll under Sql Server configuration manager - Sql Server Network configuration - Protocols for SQLEXPRESS - tcp-ip Properties - Ip Addresses. But now I get another error:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:

Comment: You either need to use integrated security, or specify the username and password you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId

is:
Go to Object explorer, click on properties (right click on Sql Server name), and on the security tab click on Sql Server and Windows authentication mode.

This worked for me.